# iOS - Is this UIPageViewController controlled by UISegmentedControl, or what is this?

Tags: ios, instagram, uisegmentedcontrol, uipageviewcontroller, transition

[image: 1] 
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

How this `UIPageViewController` can be controlled by this header which seems to be `UISegmentedControl`?

Answer (score 2):

The top bar looks like a custom control with an interesting indicator line.
This could be accomplished by putting the 2 view controllers on a `UIScrollView` side by side.
In the `UIScrollViewDelegate` implement `scrollViewDidScroll` and update the indicator line offset accordingly.

Comment: can you post an example of implemented scrollViewDodScroll with indicator line offset update?

Comment: I don't think it is scrollview because in the scrollviews, all viewcontrollers embeded in the scrollview loads and appears at the first time. On Instagram, those are separated pages controlled by that bar controller

Comment: you can use custom container view that will loaded only on viewDidAppear and add them to the scroll view. Or you can use a UIPageViewController, but who will you calculate the scroll offset?

Comment: thank you for your answer, I've reformulated the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179588/ios-different-viewcontrollers-how-to-load-them to be more precise. Do you think that there is a way to manipulate the UIPageViewController with an UISegmentedControl ?

Comment: I'll have a look there. feel free to close this post if you got an answer to your question